# OneAll social login not working with modal

Tags: 8

I am working in website in drupal 8. I am using [oneall Social login](https://www.drupal.org/project/social_login) module to allow user to log in with social media.

I am showing login page in popup/modal window but oneall social login not showing in popup.

I have searched on drupal.org and check issue for oneall social login but solution did not work.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked the data in the preprocess function? Have you checked the templates? I think your going to need to provide more information for anyone to have a shot at being able to help you.

Comment: This is bug in oneall social login module that it does not work on modal. I have fixed this with help of their support team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution with help of their support team.

Add between the  tag in your template this javascript code. Replace both XXXXXX by your OneAll subdomain :

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//XXXXXX.api.oneall.com/socialize/library.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">(function()

{ var oa=document.createElement('script'); oa.type='text/javascript'; oa.async=true; oa.src='//XXXXXX.api.oneall.com/socialize/library.js'; var os=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; os.parentNode.insertBefore(oa, os); }
)();</script>
```